# Create a jar from .net web application to use maven dependency

Tags: c#, jar, .net-4.8

I have been using for java web development for 2 years.Right now , I faced a .net framework project.I can open that project via microsoft visual studio and change some codes.I changed some codes and generated a dll.But I want to generate a jar because I want to use that jar in my java application as maven depedency.

I know how to install a jar as maven dependency to project but I have not created a jar from my .netFramework projecct.Dou have any idea ? I can only generate a dll.

Answer (score 0):

Java and C# are two different things you can't build a jar out of a c# project.

The only way I see to achieve this is by using a c# to java converter before creating the dll.